# Glibmm Application Catch Operating System Signals

Tags: c++, gtk, glibmm

I'm trying to write my first application using Glibmm and I'm confused as to how you can connect to and handle operating system signals such as SIGINT. I assume it's possible since Glib seems to have a way to do this. Do I need to write my own C++ wrapper for the Glib handler to get this functionality or is there a better way to do this that is already provided? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is not wrapped in the glibmm bindings. However, there is nothing preventing you from using the C function directly: `g_unix_signal_add()`.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I'll have to look at that some more. I was hoping that there was a nice way to do it in a C++ style way. I'll dig at it some more when I have some free time again.